# How to mock package object in scala mockito

Tags: scala, unit-testing, mockito-scala

I have a package object as :

```
package object service {
  var a = new A()
  val b = new B()
}
```

and I have scala case classes where these variables from package are used as :

```
case class function () extends Logging with Serializable {

a.callFunctioninA();

}
```

How do I mock the package object a in scala test so  I can stub the callFunctioninA to return/do nothing?

or is there a way we can mock new object call for `**new A()**` in scala using mockito-scala
??

currently when I call the function it's trying to create real object A from service and wondering how we can mock object of class A so can be used to stub callFunctioninA

Comment: You cannot. If you want it to be mockable (with mockito or manually) you have to make it injectable. You cannot hardcode some instance and then try to replace it with mock post-factum.

Comment: You can but you really shouldn't. Use dependency inversion for everything you would want to stub. Introduce an interface, make your object implement it and then costruct your function with a dependency

Answer (score 1):

At the moment of writing this answer, there is only support for [jdk 8, 11 and 14](https://github.com/mockito/mockito-scala/blob/release/1.x/.github/workflows/ci.yml#L27-L29) and [scala 2.11, 2.12 and 2.13](https://github.com/mockito/mockito-scala/blob/b9861993e54d40fc4917b149bde808fcfd0352f8/build.sbt#L29).

Since [mockito-scala 1.16.0](https://github.com/mockito/mockito-scala/tree/v1.16.0) you can [mock an object](https://github.com/mockito/mockito-scala#mocking-scala-object) but not a package object

> To enable `withObjectMocked` feature, it is mandatory to create the file `src/test/resources/mockito-extensions/org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker` containing a single line:
>
> ```
>  mock-maker-inline
> ```
>
> Example:
>
> ```scala
> object FooObject {
>   def simpleMethod: String = "not mocked!"
> }
>
> "mock" should {
>     "stub an object method" in {
>       FooObject.simpleMethod shouldBe "not mocked!"
>
>       withObjectMocked[FooObject.type] {
>         FooObject.simpleMethod returns "mocked!"
>         //or
>         when(FooObject.simpleMethod) thenReturn "mocked!"
>
>         FooObject.simpleMethod shouldBe "mocked!"
>       }
>
>       FooObject.simpleMethod shouldBe "not mocked!"
>     }
> }
> ```

---

That being said and as @[Mateusz Kubuszok](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1305121/mateusz-kubuszok) detailed in [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77882946/how-to-mock-package-object-in-scala-mockito#comment137306659_77882946)

> You cannot. If you want it to be mockable (with mockito or manually) you have to make it injectable. You cannot hardcode some instance and then try to replace it with mock post-factum.

I would say that you have a design problem. You should not put things in objects if you need to mock them. Such as a database connection handler, a kafka client, a http client of a third party service, a service with business domain logic, etc.

They are useful to contain utility methods such as some kind of transformation from one type of class to another one, a helper method to validate something that doesn't depends on other components, a factory method, etc.

The example you provided contains a mutable value that is also a shared value at the same time

> ```scala
> package object service {
>   var a = new A()
>   val b = new B()
> }
> ```

This could lead concurrent problems such as race conditions